# GPGME error on Arch Linux 32bit

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman

I need to fix this issue with GPGME error. I cannot upgrade or install anything. This is what I get in terminal:

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                    1424.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 core.sig                1424.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
error: GPGME error: No data
error: failed to update core (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
 extra                   1424.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 extra.sig               1424.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
error: GPGME error: No data
error: failed to update extra (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
 community               1424.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 community.sig           1424.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
error: GPGME error: No data
error: failed to update community (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
 archlinuxfr                7.8 KiB  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
```

I tried lots of workarounds like `pacman-key --init` and `pacman-key --populate archlinux` nothing helps.

If I edit `etc/pacman.conf` and insert `SigLevel = Never` to core and community then I get this output:

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                    1424.0   B   348K/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 extra                   1424.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 community               1424.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 archlinuxfr                7.8 KiB  2.55M/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
:: Starting full system upgrade...
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/core.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/extra.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/community.db: Unrecognized archive format
 there is nothing to do
```

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!

Finally I managed to solved this. I'll write what I've done.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/pacman/sync/*db.sig*
```

Edit & uncomment:

```
sudo nano /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

## Germany
Server = http://archlinux32.vollzornbrot.de/$arch/$repo
Server = https://archlinux32.vollzornbrot.de/$arch/$repo
Server = http://mirror.archlinux32.org/$arch/$repo
Server = https://mirror.archlinux32.org/$arch/$repo
# note: you need to resolve via openNIC (or similar) to access the next mirror
#Server = http://mirror.archlinux32.oss/$arch/$repo
```

Then:

```
sudo pacman-key --init

sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux

sudo pacman -Syy

sudo pacman -Syyu
```

Done!

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me. Situation remains the same.

Comment: If that still fails, I recommend editing your mirrorlist. `sudo pacman-mirrors -i` can be quite helpful in generating a custom list for your location. After that, run `pacman -Syyu`.