# Arch Linux Installation - GPG Errors and Unrecognized Archive Format

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, gpg, pacman

I got a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 and have been trying to boot Arch from an ISO that I burned onto a 4 GB USB stick.

The ISO image is burned correctly and is not corrupted. The partition created on my SSD are:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1     8G      swap
/dev/nvme0n1p2     469G    ext4
```

I've tried out the following:

Originally, `timedatectl set-ntp true` did not retrieve the right timezone so I manually set it to Europe/Zurich which works. I checked with `timedatectl status` and it is okay now.

I checked that the ip link is up and running by pinging archlinux.org (or whatever other website).

I followed the Installation guide and instructions I found on some community help pages to run:

1. `dirmngr < /dev/null`
   This creates the `/root/.gnupg` directory and cache.
2. `pacman-key --init`
   This gives me -

```
gpg: Generating pacman keyring master key
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory
gpg: key generation failed: No such file or directory
Updating trust database
No need for a trustdb check
```

Note: I have also tried to either edit pacman.conf to provide a `--gpgdir` as `/root/.gnupg` after generating a gpg key using `gpg2 --gen-key`
Successfully generated my own gpg key and pacman-init did create the secring using this directory as home. I tried to update GPGDir in pacman.conf to point to `/root/.gnupg` but did not notice any difference in the outcome.

3. `pacman-init --populate archlinux
   This command usually completes without error when I do not generate my own gpg key. If I do follow my own keygen and then run pacman-init and populate the error is as follows:

```
Locally signing key <alphanumeric keyname>
ERROR: <alphanumeric keyname> could not be locally signed.
```

This message repeats for all the keys (6 times).

However, if I run pacman-init **without** generating my own gpg key (but after running `dirmngr < /dev/null`) then the populate proceeds smoothly. (remember that in this case the `pacman-key --init` had failed to migrate the secring).

4. `pacman-key --refresh-keys` runs into an (expected?) error of -

```
Refreshing 112 keys from hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
A specified local key could not be refreshed from the keyserver.
```

I have also run gpg --refresh-keys between step 1 and 2 which gives the same error. Is this expected?

5. `pacman -Syu` (also -Sy -Syyuu) same error -

```
error: GPGME error: No data
error: failed to update core, community, extra (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: failed to synchronize all databases
```

6. `pacstrap /mnt base`

```
Creating install root at /mnt
Installing packages to /mnt
error: GPGME error: No data
failed to update core, community, extra (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: failed to synchronize all databases
```

I assume it runs `pacman -S` first so it is logical for it to throw the exact same error.

To solve this, I cleared the cache with `pacman -Scc` and also tried to replace the *.db files in `var/lib/pacman/sync` with those from `ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/archlinux/community/os/x86_64/community.db` and `ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/archlinux/extra/os/x86_64/extra.db` but the `wget` command hangs and does not complete. Not sure why this is the case.

I have also edited the pacman.conf to set `SigLevel = TrustAll Optional` or simply to `TrustAll` which seems, I believe the most basic/no verification.

I have been through the [Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) and the Wiki and retried installation from scratch twice. I have also solicited help from friends who have installed and have been working with Arch Linux but to no avail.

**Update:** I followed this [Arch Installation Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475236/gpgme-error-on-arch-linux-32bit) and basically "sudo-ed" the init, populate, and sync commands. I also updated my mirrorlist to point to (only) some German servers.

The init and populate still failed with errors. But the sync worked (`sudo pacman -Syy`). However, when I try `sudo pacman -Syyu` it fails with `error: unrecognized archive format` for the *.db files. Not sure what I did wrong but will retry from scratch and update this post.

I am guessing I should change up the mirrors because that seems to be an issue. Then I need to re-run the sync (do I also need to re-init and repopulate the keys?).

Comment: `pacman-key` does not generally required. Follow the [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) step by step, word by word.